# How Count & Display the number of items

Tags: ce-1.9.0.1

How Count & Display the number of items to frontend? What PHP code is needed?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$collection = Mage::getResourceModel('reports/product_collection');
$collection->addStoreFilter();
echo $total = $collection->getSize();
```